# Javascript/php version of site

Tags: php, javascript

I'm having trouble making my site function well both in JS, and *without* JS.

I have two standalone versions working just fine. Now, I have a photo-album. In the Javascript version, there is a [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). There's the overview of all photos inside an album, and clicking an image will open up that image in FancyBox. In decent browsers, the url even changes with the `ID` of the image, so you can share an image easily. When the Javascript version is called with an image, the FancyBox gets loaded automatically.

The issue is with the `non JS version`. Here we have the same overview of all the images in the album, but the links are different. To solve this, I use the following script:

`<noscript><!-- all the images here --></noscript>`

for the non-JS version, and

`<div class='jsonly'><!-- all the images here --></div>` with

`<noscript><style>.jsonly{display:none;}</style></noscript>`

Now the **issue is that I'd rather not have the whole js-version in the background of the php-version, because this is a rather biggy and also requires two extra queries**. To try and circumvent these troubles, I used JS to set a cookie if JS is enabled, so I could filter it out in PHP. The issue with this however is, that when a user had JS enabled and suddenly doesn't anymore, it will still present the JS-version because of the cookie that's still there.

What are common solutions for problems like these? Should I just put it all in the background, or neglect the fact that some people might need to push a button to go back to the JS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the logic backwards. If you want something to be visible only when JS is enabled, then you BY DEFAULT hide that content, then use JS to show it.

```
<div class="jsonly">...</div>

<style>
   .jsonly {
       display: none; /* hide by default */
   }
</style>
<script>
    $('.jsonly').show(); // will only work if jquery/JS is available.
</script>
```

Comment: It would be so cool if Javascript had an "isJavascriptEnabled()" function.

Comment: what would be the point? you'd need JS to run that function, so by definition you'd already have your answer.

Comment: It would be so cool if users here had a "detectSarcasm()" method  ;)  I've honestly seen it once on a forum somewhere, somebody had created:

    function isJSEnabled() { return true; }

Sheer brilliance.

Comment: That part of my code does work though. If js is enabled, the .jsonly does not get hidden and the content of the `<noscript>` tags are hidden. When js is not enabled, the .jsonly style will be applied and .jsonly will be hidden. Works, with pure css.

This however is not the issue I'm having.